How can I set the system properties of an ImageCollection from python code?
I have an imlage collection tha I update on regular basis with new images.
Whenver I add an image I want to update the system:time_end property of the ImageCollection asset.
When I try the following code:
collection =  projects/ldc-main-crop/assets/USDA/crop-condition
millis = datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000
ee.data.setAssetProperties(collection, {"system:time_end": millis})

I get the following error:

ee.ee_exception.EEException: Property key "system:time_end" is invalid.

What am I doing wrong ?

Looking at the doc in the javascript API, it says ee.data.setAssetProperties is DEPRECATED: Use ee.data.updateAsset(). You may want to also check if this is the case for Python.

it uses updateAsset under the hood the problem is unrelated to deprecation. The issue is that I don't know what name I should use to update the system properties and I cannot find a consistent list in the documentation. If it's effectively "time_end" then why cannot I update it ?

I got the answer for another asset type, I think my asset was not correctly defined.
How to set the start_time and end_time Asset property programatically?
